# composite scale to measure child-parent relationship

Tags: scales, measurement

For my research on Mental health problems and correlates, child-parent relationship have identified as a correlate. Child-parent relationship is planned to measure with 6 questions and each question have five point scale of answers
Example-

question    Strongly agree      Agree   Neither agree/disagree   disagree    Strongly disagree
1
2
3
4
5

Is it justifiable if I score them 5,4,3,2,1 and take the sum for each item and add up scores of 5 items together.
Can I decide on cutoff points to categorized study participnts in to three groups like good relatioship, neutral relationship and poor relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding them, you want to make sure they go well together into one scale. Typical methods to do this include factor analysis (you want all the items to load on one factor) and Cronbach's alpha. You might then use the sum or a factor score.

There is also a lot of work that should have gone into the 6 questions (validation, pilot testing, etc). To develop a good questionnaire is actually a fairly involved process. People often skimp on this process and you may get away with doing so, but it could affect the quality of results you get when using the scale.